# Airplay stop playing video streaming when app is in background or device locked

Tags: ios, video-streaming, avplayerviewcontroller, airplay, ios-background-mode

I'am using an AVPlayerViewController for playing video in streaming.

When I launch Airplay on the AVPlayerViewController on the Apple TV and put the app in background or if I lock the device, the video paused on the Apple TV.

I verify that like in this post [https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1668/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010209][1]

I had check the background audio, airplay mode
My audio Session is started and active in AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
My AVPlayer is in playing mode when I go in background or if I lock the device

I read the 'Special Considerations for Video Media' paragraph of this post [https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1668/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010209][1], but they don't spoke about the AVPlayerViewController.

I understand that video is not one of the possible background mode capabilities but Airplay is.

So do you have any way to have the video stream audio/image playing with the app' in background or device locked using the AVPlayerViewController ?

Thank you in advance for your advices or any technical link that I would have missed.

Answer (score 1):

**Xcode 13**

All I had to do was enable background mode `Audio, Airplay, and Picture in Picture`. To do this, just select your target, add background modes and tick the checkbox for **Audio, Airplay, and Picture in Picture**.

Then set the category of the AV session. I did this just before the video played.

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
    try audioSession.setCategory(.playback)
} catch {
    print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed.")
}
```

It then supported playing video over airplay while the device is locked. I was using an `AVPlayerViewController`.